# What's the difference between "Cross Country Running" and "Trail Running"?

Tags: meaning, sports

"Trail running" shoes differs markedly from "road running" shoes and "track running" shoes. I can understand these categories. But I also found an event entitled "Cross Country Running Event". Can the "Cross Country Running Event" be treated as "Trail Running Event"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross-country races are largely run on trails of all sorts, ranging from hard-packed dirt to gravel. Depending on the course, you may even hit some pavement along the way. In general, though, you can treat cross-country running as a trail event.

#### Note on usage

*Trail running* is used to indicate any running not done on the road or pavement. *Cross country* usually refers to the organized sport of running 5k/8k/10k distances off-road. If someone says, "I run cross country", then, more likely than not, that person is on a team and races regularly. Someone who says, "I'm a trail-runner", runs on trails but not necessarily competitively. And you would probably be hard-pressed to find "Trail Racing" or "Trail Running Racing"! Rather, it's almost always "Cross Country Racing".

**Hard-core runners will normally race the course in spikes (metal or rubber) for added traction and speed. Regular trail shoes are way too heavy for racing (13 oz versus 8 oz). Of course, your choice of shoes would depend on your goals or the level of the event.*

Comment: It's great help to me. Thank you. I can understand what your said completely.

Comment: You're most welcome.